# node.js strange syntax for "delete"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

what's the delete used for? I didn't see such grammar before, can anybody help me?
the code snippet is very easy and it is used the node.js , mongoose , mongodb

```
function _update(game, callback) {
    if (!game) {
        callback(new Error("Game must be provided."));
        return;
    }
    if (!game.gameId) {
        callback(new Error("Game id should be provided"));
        return;
    }

    var updates = (game instanceof Game) ? game.toObject() : game;
    delete updates._id;
    updates.modifiedDate = new Date();

    Game.findOneAndUpdate({"_id": game.id, "deleted" : {"$ne": true}}, updates, callback);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`delete` in JavaScript [removes the property from the object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete).

```
var game = {
    id: 1
}

console.log(game);  // Object {id: 1}

delete game.id

console.log(game);  // undefined
```

Comment: No problem, that is what this site is for! Your question was valid and worth asking, please do not apologize for working to improve yourself!

Answer (score 1):

It is used to remove a property from an object. So in this instance it removes the _id property from updates